# How to fill a pickerview with data and run an activity indicator at the same time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, performselector

I have a method to load data from a web service and fill an array, it works fine (let's call it "get_data"). I use this array ("arr") as datasource for a picker view ("pv"), it also works fine, when I run my app, the pickerview is full with items. One day I decided to use an "activity indicator" ("ai"), and now "pv" is always empty, and I have no idea how to fix it. Next is my code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[ai startAnimation]; // ACTIVITY INDICATOR STARTS SPINNING.
[self performSelector:@selector( get_data )  // FILL ARRAY.
           withObject:nil
           afterDelay:0]; }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void) get_data { // CALL WEB SERVICE, FILL ARRAY WITH JSON DATA.
[ai stopAnimation]; }  // SPINNING STOPS AFTER LONG TASK.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return 1; }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)pickerView :(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
 numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [arr count]; }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [arr objectAtIndex:row]; }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
       didSelectRow:(NSInteger )row
        inComponent:(NSInteger )component {
index = [pv selectedRowInComponent:0]; } // INDEX IS A GLOBAL INT.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
- ( NSAttributedString * ) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
                attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row
                         forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
NSString * title = [arr objectAtIndex:row];
NSAttributedString * attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                 initWithString:title attributes:
                                 @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:
                                 [UIColor blackColor]}];
return attString; }
```

I have used "activity indicators" before with "performSelector", and they have worked fine. What I don't understand is why the pickerview methods aren't working anymore with the array, so, my question is: How to fill a pickerview with data and run an activity indicator at the same time?

If I change my viewDidLoad like this, pickerview works, but activity indicator doesn't :

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
/* [ai startAnimation]; // ACTIVITY INDICATOR STARTS SPINNING.
[self performSelector:@selector( get_data )  // FILL ARRAY.
           withObject:nil
           afterDelay:0]; */
[self get_data];
}
```

Comment: Try putting a break point in any of your picker data source methods to see if they get hit after your web service finishes and your activity indicator stops. And make sure that `arr` contains the objects that you think it contains.

Comment: Dear Stonz2, I did what you suggested, arr is full with data, but pickerview methods don't execute at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `performSelector:`, it executes on the same thread as though you had simply called the selector directly.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [ai startAnimation]; // ACTIVITY INDICATOR STARTS SPINNING.
  [self performSelector:@selector( get_data )  // FILL ARRAY.
             withObject:nil
             afterDelay:0];
}

- (void) get_data {
  // CALL WEB SERVICE, FILL ARRAY WITH JSON DATA.
  [ai stopAnimation];  // SPINNING STOPS AFTER LONG TASK.
}
```

This is identical to:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [ai startAnimation]; // ACTIVITY INDICATOR STARTS SPINNING.
  [self get_data];  // FILL ARRAY.
}
```

or simply:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [ai startAnimation]; // ACTIVITY INDICATOR STARTS SPINNING.
  // CALL WEB SERVICE, FILL ARRAY WITH JSON DATA.
  [ai stopAnimation]; // SPINNING STOPS AFTER LONG TASK.
}
```

---

If your web service is executing in a different thread or a block and allows you to attach a completion responder, you should put your `[ai stopAnimation];` in there.

If this is not the case and you are synchronously calling to a web service for data on the main thread (**don't ever perform blocking network operations on the main thread**), you could instead shift it all to a background thread:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [ai startAnimation]; // ACTIVITY INDICATOR STARTS SPINNING.
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0L), ^{
  // CALL WEB SERVICE, FILL ARRAY WITH JSON DATA.
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [ai stopAnimations]; // SPINNING STOPS AFTER LONG TASK.
  });
});
```

Comment: I just tried your code, but the pickerview still empty, and the activity indicator doesn't spin (but the array is full of data). I did what Stonz2 sugested, I put a breakpoint in "numberOfComponentsInPickerView", and the pickerview methods are executed, but without the breakpoint, they don't execute. This is really freaking me out.

Comment: Thanks, Ian, actually, your answer worked, with a little help of Stonz2 : I

Comment: Sorry, I exceeded the 5 min limit to edit comments, I just switched windows and the comment was sent, this is the comment : I took "reloadAllComponents" from Stonz2 and put it before "stopAnimations" of Ian's code, and now Ian's code works. I will give points to both, and Ian's answer is the right one. Thanks, buddies.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your picker view's `dataSource` and `delegate` are set. After your web service finishes, you need to reload your picker's data source with the updated `arr`.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
pv.dataSource = self;
pv.delegate = self;
[ai startAnimation]; // ACTIVITY INDICATOR STARTS SPINNING.
[self performSelector:@selector( get_data )  // FILL ARRAY.
           withObject:nil
           afterDelay:0]; }

- (void) get_data {
  // CALL WEB SERVICE, FILL ARRAY WITH JSON DATA.
  [ai stopAnimation];  // SPINNING STOPS AFTER LONG TASK.
  [pv reloadAllComponents];
}
```

Comment: Nothing seems to work. If I remove the performSelector the pickerview works perfectly, so there is something about the performSelector and the lifecycle that is making the pickerview methods not to work.

Comment: I took "reloadAllComponents" from Stonz2 and put it before "stopAnimations" of Ian's code, and now Ian's code works. I will give points to both, and Ian's answer is the right one. Thanks, buddies.